# Getting the output of several MySQL queries all together

Tags: mysql, bash

I am writing a script thats gets some data from different mysql tables:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/mysql --password=****** --database=mydb<<EOMYSQL
select field1, field2 from table1 left join table2 on etc
into outfile '/home/jm/mysql/file1.txt';
select field3 from table3 left join table4 on etc
into outfile '/home/jm/mysql/file2.txt';
select field4,field5,field6,field7 from table5 left join table6 on etc
into outfile '/home/jm/mysql/file3.txt';
EOMYSQL
```

My "problem" is that I need to use 3 differents output files, and merge them afterwards.
Is there any way to get the output of the 3 queries all together?, like:

```
field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 field6 field7
```

Thanks,

PS: tried "union all" but looks like requieres same number of fields per query.

Comment: On what criteria are you joining the three queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing any sample data or even your table structures, if you want to perform this in SQL then you *might* be able to use the following.

If you have a field that can be joined on between each of the query results, then you could use a `LEFT JOIN` to return data:

```
select *
from
(
  select t1.field1, t1.field2
  from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2
    on t1.field1 = t2.field1
) t1t2
left join
(
  select t3.field3
  from table3 t3
  left join table4 t4
    on t3.field3 = t4.field3
) t3t4
  on t1t2.field1 = t3t4.field3
left join
(
  select t5.field4, t5.field5, t5.field6, t5.field7
  from table5 t5
  left join table6 t6
    on t5.field4 = t6.field4
) t5t6
  on t1t2.field1 = t5t6.field4;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c21cd/5)

If you do not have a field that could be joined on, then you could use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select *
from
(
  select t1.field1, t1.field2
  from table1 t1
  left join table2 t2
    on t1.field1 = t2.field1
) t1t2
cross join
(
  select t3.field3
  from table3 t3
  left join table4 t4
    on t3.field3 = t4.field3
) t3t4
cross join
(
  select t5.field4, t5.field5, t5.field6, t5.field7
  from table5 t5
  left join table6 t6
    on t5.field4 = t6.field4
) t5t6;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c21cd/6)

Comment: Just great. One output, as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `UNION` requires the same number of fields for each query, but you can fill them for example with an empty string:

```
select field1, field2, "", "", "", "", "" from table1 left join table2 on etc
union
select "", "", field3, "", "", "", "" from table3 left join table4 on etc
union
select "", "", "", field4, field5, field6, field7 from table5 left join table6 on etc
```

You can also use `NULL`:

```
select field1, field2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL from table1 left join table2 on etc
union
select NULL, NULL, field3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL from table3 left join table4 on etc
union
select NULL, NULL, NULL, field4, field5, field6, field7 from table5 left join table6 on etc
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution looks fine, but the output has 3 rows instead of the desired one.

Comment: Which is the case with your three-file solution, too. If you don't want that you need to specifiy a join condition.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join those files by column, you should use the `paste` utility:

```
cd /home/jm/mysql/
paste file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

Comment: Thanks I would prefer to get a sole oputput, instead of having to deal with 3 files.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need the `paste` command.

```
% cat A.csv 
dog,cat
bird,tiger

% cat B.csv 
bear,lion
weasel,trout

% paste -d, A.csv B.csv 
dog,cat,bear,lion
bird,tiger,weasel,trout
```

The `-d` flag changes the delimiter (the default is TAB).

Comment: Thanks I would prefer to get a sole oputput, instead of having to deal with 3 files.